# Web scraping doesn't iterate over entire webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape the information of all the player names and player rating from this website:
https://www.fifaindex.com/players/?gender=0&league=1&order=desc

But i only get the information from the first player on the page.

The code im using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.fifaindex.com/players/?gender=0&league=1&order=desc"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', class_="responsive-table table-rounded")

for result in results:
    rating = result.find("span", class_="badge badge-dark rating r3").text
    name = result.find("a", class_="link-player")
    info = [rating, name]
    print(info)
```

The HTML parsed is attached in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51hBQ.png)

Comment: What's `result.content` if you have `page`? And where's `list` coming from in the `for loop`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: **Note:** *Avoid using `python` reserved terms ([`keywords`][1]), this could have unwanted effects on the results of your code.*

Comment: the iteration variable `result` is not used anywhere inside your loop. do you mean `result.find(...)` instead of `list.find(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered around a little bit and I think I got a version that does what you want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.fifaindex.com/players/? 
gender=0&league=1&order=desc")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("tr")

for result in results:
    try:
        result["data-playerid"]
    except KeyError:
        continue

    rating = result.find("span", class_="badge badge-dark rating r3").text
    name = result.find("a", class_="link-player")
    info = [rating, name]
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all table lines with a data-playerid attribute will fix it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.fifaindex.com/players/?gender=0&league=1&order=desc"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('tr', {'data-playerid': True})

for res in results:
    rating = res.find("span", class_="badge badge-dark rating r3").text
    name = res.find("a", class_="link-player")
    info = [rating, name]
    print(info)
```